# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem

I was installing a custom look in SharePoint 2013 on-premise and after applying the custom look, my home page doesn't load and showing me the following error. Please help me to fix it,

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint,
>   Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the deployed solution is only supported for `SharePoint 2016`! so it will not work in `SharePoint 2013` farm **because** the SP 2016 assembly version `Version=16.0.0.0` is not located in the current SharePoint 2013 Farm!

**So,** Try to [uninstall the deployed solution](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/12/20/uninstall-sharepoint-wsp-solutions/) to get your page working again!

**Check also** [INSTALL AND DEPLOY SHAREPOINT SOLUTION PACKAGE (WSP) USING POWERSHELL](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/12/20/how-to-deploy-a-sharepoint-wsp-solution-package/)

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, i was out. Thank you for your response, i appreciate it.

Comment: No issue, please if the answer helped you don't forget to mark it as accepted :)